# Why can't I add the equations of two lines to find out how many solutions the system has?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many solutions does this pair of equations have?

$3x-6y=9$

$2y-x=3$

I know now that these equations represent parallel lines and are not the same line, so there are no solutions. I can also see that if I had solved for $y$, I could have observed that they have the same slope but different intercepts and so hopefully have realized that the correct answer was "no solutions".

But I originally started out by adding the two equations, like so:

$3x-6y-9=0$

$+$

$-x +2y-3=0$

$=$

$2x-4y-12=0$

I thought I could factor out a 2, then factor the quadratic. The question asked how many solutions, and I could see that the discriminant is positive, so even though it wasn't clear what the roots were, I thought there should be two.

What is wrong with this reasoning? How should I have noticed I was on the wrong track once I had already started adding the two equations?

Comment: What do you mean by "factor the quadratic"? There is no such a quadratic equation in this problem, if you factor out a $2$ you get $x = 2y + 6$, then by substituting to one of the other equations you will get

\begin{equation*}
3(2y+6) - 6y -9 = 0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
9 = 0
\end{equation*}

which makes no sense; so the system has no solutions.

Comment: As Klaramun said, there was no quadratic to factor. In general, when you're adding equations, you want one of the terms to cancel out. So what you actually wanted was to multiply the second equation by 3, and then add them together. By doing so, you'd find that you got $-18=0$, which clearly has no solutions.

Comment: I have no idea why I was assuming there was an x^2 term here. Thanks for clearing up that part of my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens if you scale the second equation by $3$ first before adding:
$$
\begin{cases}
3x - 6y = 9 \\
-x + 2y = 3
\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases}
3x - 6y = 9 \\
-3x + 6y = 9
\end{cases}
\implies 0 = 18
$$
This is a contradiction! So no solutions exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue arises from the fact that your steps are not reversible. You started off with the following two equations:
$$2y-x=3.$$
$$3x-6y=9$$
You then added them to get:
$$2x-4y=12$$
Dividing both sides by $-2$ and rearranging gives:
$$2y-x=-6.$$
Here's where you arrive at a contradiction: equating the most recent equation to the first of your two original equations gives $-6=3$, which is clearly false. Of course, I still haven't answered your question of "why is this wrong"? Basically, it all boils down to the fact that your steps are not reversible. Yes, you can add two equations together to get a new valid equation, but a solution to your new equation is by no means guaranteed to satisfy your second equation, as I demonstrated above by arriving at the contradiction $-6=3$. Because your steps are not reversible, it is good practice to always check your answers at the end of a problem by plugging them into your original equations.